# Como ao clicar numa ImageView não interfierir na aplicação?

Tags: java, android, xml

Tenho um `Linear Layout`

```
               <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:onClick="onClickAcao">

               </LinearLayout>

      public void image(ImageView image,int rid,LinearLayout linear )
    {
        image.setBackgroundResource(rid);

        linear.addView(image);
    }
```

E nesse `Linear layout` vai uma `ImagemView` criada via código, com a `imagemView` criada no `Linear Layout` como imagem que pega todo o `Linear Layout` ao clicar nele não executa ação do linear Layout, Tem como fazer a `ImagemView` não interferir na ação?.

Comment: Poste o código da criação da *ImageView*.

Comment: Se o imageView vai ocupar todo o espaço você poderia setar o click no imageView ou isso atrapalharia?

Comment: @ramaral tá lá o código

Comment: @CaiqueOliveira isso atrapalharia

Comment: Se o código é só esse não vejo razão para que `onClickAcao` do *LinearLayout* não seja chamado.

Comment: @ramaral realmente a função está sendo chamado, o erro esta na comparação de imagem `R.drawable.image`

Comment: Necessariamente tenque adicionar uma ImageView? Não poderia trabalhar com o próprio background do LinearLayout?

Comment: Não entendi. O que quer dizer com: *"o erro esta na comparação de imagem...."*?

Comment: @ramaral já resolvi é o seguinte tinha  armazenado o id das figura em um vetor de inteiros ao comparar não está identificando que era iguais, que eu fiz converti para `String` e fiz a comparação usando `.equals()` e deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente a `ImagemView` não atrapalhou para chamar a função `onClickAcao`do `Linear Layout`